# Nutch not crawling url specified in seed.txt

Tags: solr, lucene, nutch

I have just installed nutch integrated with solr and started crawling. but the urls I am specifying in seed.txt nutch is not crawling those url immediately. It's injecting old urls which I may have given earlier but now they are commented out.It looks like nutch is injecting url's in some strange order. What is the reason.also could anybody guide me any book or detailed tutorial on nutch becuase most of the tutorial available are only installation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sites are crawled even when the URL is removed from seed.txt (Nutch 2.1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044906/sites-are-crawled-even-when-the-url-is-removed-from-seed-txt-nutch-2-1)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16065297/1162491) to a similar question, the old URLs are still in Nutch's `crawldb`.

You can nuke your previous runs completely like [this user did](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/nutch-user/201408.mbox/%3COF5F439F05.12C3136D-ONC1257D32.0045E0A0-C1257D32.00481094@adv-boeblingen.de%3E) and start fresh, or you can remove the unwanted URLs a few different ways via [CrawlDbMerger](https://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.9/org/apache/nutch/crawl/CrawlDbMerger.Merger.html):

- CLI via [bin/nutch mergedb](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20mergedb)
- CLI via [bin/nutch updatedb](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20updatedb)